# configure power restore policy HP ProLiant BL2x220c G6

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, electrical-power, bios, blade-server

After each reboot my server automatically powers on:

```
Power Overload       : false
Power Interlock      : inactive
Main Power Fault     : false
Power Control Fault  : false
**Power Restore Policy : always-on**
Last Power Event     :
Chassis Intrusion    : inactive
Front-Panel Lockout  : inactive
Drive Fault          : false
Cooling/Fan Fault    : false
Front Panel Control  : none
```

How to change the Power Restore Policy from command line to always-off ?

I mean after each power failure. I've tried to configure it using ipmitool ... but I can't figure out how to change it. OS: linux.

It is a linux cluster for scientists, all nodes are worker nodes. If the power goes down it's not a problem. We don't have ups for it. I would like to power it later due to problems with network switches. They starts slower and cause problems with when blades boots. Thank you for an idea to fix it.

I've checked my OA and there is:

```
SET SERVER POWERDELAY { ALL | <bay number> [{- | ,} <bay number>] } { number of
seconds to delay power | NOPOWERON }: Sets the PowerDelay status for the
specified server or range of servers. If the delay is zero, the delay has no
effect on the device. If the delay is NOPOWERON, the device cannot poweron until
all devices have completed their delays.
```

so it only delays booting. I would like to disable automatic turn on. I can login to each server through webbrowser (to ILO), but I have to many servers to do this. So my question is still open.

Comment: Well, a reboot (as opposed to a shutdown) *should* turn the power on.

Comment: Not enough information... What operating system are you using? What are you actually doing? This is a blade server.

Comment: Can you please explain why you don't want the servers to power on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a blade server. Your power control is partially dictated by the chassis Onboard Administrator. You can disable automatic power-on for all blades with:

```
SET SERVER POWERDELAY ALL NOPOWERON
```

Or you can set this from the ILO web interface directly for an individual blade...

Or you can set this in the BIOS.

But really:

- You shouldn't be experiencing sudden power loss to your blade systems. Fix that first. You run the risk of other problems by not protecting your power.
- Restored power state is the norm and usually the desired effect if there's a power outage.
- Why would you want the system to stay off?
- Is this system fully under your control?

---

Edit:

For standalone servers, you can use the [HP SmartStart Scripting Toolkit](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219389) or `conrep`/`hprcu` command to set the "Automatic Power-On" feature in the system BIOS to the desired behavior. This may not work for your blade systems because they're operating on the assumption that you have stable power.

From the script XML documentation:

> "Configures server to automatically power on when A/C power is applied
>   to the system. This setting is not support by blade servers."

Comment: Or you can have the blades power on after intervals, which is probably a better idea, since this is probably a boot storm.

Comment: These servers also support a RANDOM power-on delay setting.